# Parallelise Hbase Scan using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, pyspark

My Hbase row key: user + "-" + timestamp, where user is the name of the user. Same user can have multiple entries with different timestamp in the rowkey.

Use Case: Pick HBase Records between user + "_" + timestamp_start till user + "_" + timestamp_end for each user in the users list.

timestamp_start < timestamp_end

Current Implementation that is working but it is serialised on users:

```py
users = [user1, user2, ....] #30 million users   
sc = SparkContext()
conf = dict()

for user in users:
        # some config params go here
        conf["hbase.mapreduce.scan.row.start"] = user + "-" + str(timestamp_start)
        conf["hbase.mapreduce.scan.row.stop"] = user + "-" + str(timestamp_end)

        hbase_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
        keyConverter=keyConv,
        valueConverter=valueConv,
        conf=conf) #this conf is same conf created above
```

Is there any way to parallelize the Hbase scan on the list of users with subjectively specifying the start-row and end-row for each user as full scan takes huge time to process?

Comment: Do you know how many regions your scan need to run on? If all the data you are trying to scan is in one region, it will create only one paration in the RDD because it loading data from one server.